# Write multiple Numpy arrays of different dtype as columns of CSV file

Tags: python, csv, numpy

What would be the best way to write multiple numpy arrays of different dtype as different columns of a single CSV file?

For instance, given the following arrays:

```
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])

array([[ 10.,  20.],
       [ 30.,  40.],
       [ 50.,  60.]])
```

I would like to obtain a file (delimiter irrelevant):

```
1 2 10.0 20.0
3 4 30.0 40.0
5 6 50.0 60.0
```

Optimally, I would like to be able to write a list of arrays this way, where a format/dtype can be different for every array.

I tried looking at `savetxt`, but it's not clear to me how to use it if the arrays have a different type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [38]: a=np.arange(1,7).reshape(3,2)
In [39]: b=np.arange(10,70.,10).reshape(3,2)
In [40]: c=np.concatenate((a,b),axis=1)
In [41]: c
Out[41]: 
array([[  1.,   2.,  10.,  20.],
       [  3.,   4.,  30.,  40.],
       [  5.,   6.,  50.,  60.]])
```

All values are float; default `savetxt` is a general float:

```
In [43]: np.savetxt('test.csv',c)
In [44]: cat test.csv
1.000000000000000000e+00 2.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+01 2.000000000000000000e+01
3.000000000000000000e+00 4.000000000000000000e+00 3.000000000000000000e+01 4.000000000000000000e+01
5.000000000000000000e+00 6.000000000000000000e+00 5.000000000000000000e+01 6.000000000000000000e+01
```

With a custom `fmt` I can get:

```
In [46]: np.savetxt('test.csv',c,fmt='%2d %2d %5.1f %5.1f')
In [47]: cat test.csv
 1  2  10.0  20.0
 3  4  30.0  40.0
 5  6  50.0  60.0
```

More generally we can make a `c` with a compound dtype.  It isn't needed here with just floats and ints, but with strings it would matter.  But we still need a long `fmt` to display the columns correctly.

`np.rec.fromarrays` is an easy way to generate a structured arrays.  Unfortunately it only works with flattened arrays.  So for your (3,2) arrays I need to list the columns separately.

```
In [52]: c = np.rec.fromarrays((a[:,0],a[:,1],b[:,0],b[:,1]))
In [53]: c
Out[53]: 
rec.array([(1, 2, 10.0, 20.0), (3, 4, 30.0, 40.0), (5, 6, 50.0, 60.0)], 
          dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<f8'), ('f3', '<f8')])
In [54]: np.savetxt('test.csv',c,fmt='%2d %2d %5.1f %5.1f')
In [55]: cat test.csv
 1  2  10.0  20.0
 3  4  30.0  40.0
 5  6  50.0  60.0
```

I'm using the same `savetxt`.

I could also make a structured array with 2 fields, each being 2 columns.  I'm not sure if `savetxt` would work with that or not.

`savetxt` essentially iterates over the 1st dimension of your array, and does a formatted write on each row, roughly:

```
for row in arr:
    f.write(fmt%tuple(row))
```

where `fmt` is derived from your parameter.

It wouldn't be hard to write your own version that iterates on 2 arrays, and does a separate formatted write for each pair of rows.

```
for r1,r2 in zip(a,b):
    print('%2d %2d'%tuple(r1), '%5.1f %5.1f'%tuple(r2))
```

===================

Trying a compound dtype

```
In [60]: np.dtype('2i,2f')
Out[60]: dtype([('f0', '<i4', (2,)), ('f1', '<f4', (2,))])
In [61]: c=np.zeros(a.shape[0], np.dtype('2i,2f'))
In [62]: c['f0']=a
In [63]: c['f1']=b
In [64]: c
Out[64]: 
array([([1, 2], [10.0, 20.0]), ([3, 4], [30.0, 40.0]),
       ([5, 6], [50.0, 60.0])], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4', (2,)), ('f1', '<f4', (2,))])
In [65]: np.savetxt('test.csv',c,fmt='%2d %2d %5.1f %5.1f')
---
ValueError: fmt has wrong number of % formats:  %2d %2d %5.1f %5.1f
```

So writing a compound dtype like this does not work.  Considering that a row of `c` looks like:

```
In [69]: tuple(c[0]) 
Out[69]: (array([1, 2], dtype=int32), array([ 10.,  20.], dtype=float32))
```

I shouldn't be surprised.

I can save the two blocks with `%s` format, but that leaves me with brackets.

```
In [66]: np.savetxt('test.csv',c,fmt='%s %s')
In [67]: cat test.csv
[1 2] [ 10.  20.]
[3 4] [ 30.  40.]
[5 6] [ 50.  60.]
```

I think there is a `np.rec` function that flattens the dtype.  But I can also do that with a `view`:

```
In [72]: np.savetxt('test.csv',c.view('i,i,f,f'),fmt='%2d %2d %5.1f %5.1f')
In [73]: cat test.csv
 1  2  10.0  20.0
 3  4  30.0  40.0
 5  6  50.0  60.0
```

So as long as you are dealing with numeric values, the simple concatenate is just as good as the more complex structured approaches.

============

Comment: Nice overview of all possibilities, including the structured arrays, which is a good solution if strings must be written as well.

Answer (score 1):

use `np.concatenate` in order to concatenate the arrays along the second axis then use [`np.savetxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html#numpy.savetxt) inorder to save your array in a a text format.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2],
              [3, 4],
              [5, 6]])

b = np. array([[10., 20.],
               [30., 40.],
               [50., 60.]])

np.savetxt('filename.csv', np.concatenate((a,b), axis=1))
```

Note that [`np.savetxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html#numpy.savetxt) also accepts another arguments like `delimiter`.

> `numpy.savetxt(fname, X, fmt='%.18e', delimiter=' ', newline='\n', header='', footer='', comments='# ')`

Comment: With this all columns will be written as floats.

Comment: @hpaulj By default yeah, for other format we should pass another one to `fmt`.